# Shell script - convert Excel (xlsx) to CSV - remove blank space / tab space

Tags: excel, shell, csv, unix, ubuntu

I receive excel file (xslx) with multiple sheets for my project. The number of records on these sheets ranges from 15k to 70k per sheet. I need to perform following tasks on this data and then convert it to CSV. Or covert to CSV and then process the data either way its fine.

Input Example:

```
call_no  uniq_no  Type  Strength    Description
2456     15       TX    SomeSting        SomeSting
5263     15       BLL      SomeSting   SomeSting
4263     162      TX                SomeSting
2369     215      LH    SomeSting
4269     426      BLL   SomeSting       SomeSting
7412     162      TX    SomeSting   SomeSting
```

As per the requirement i need to

1. Find duplicate values in column 'uniq_no' and delete all duplicate records except the original record (first record).
2. Replace blanks with data. (Just simple find blank and replace with value logic)
3. Remove space/tab space in any cell. (This point is not important, its just like a side-quest)

Output Example:

```
call_no  uniq_no  Type  Strength    Description
2456     15       TX    SomeSting   SomeSting
4263     162      TX    **NewDATA** SomeSting
2369     215      LH    SomeSting   **NewDATA**
4269     426      BLL   SomeSting   SomeSting
```

This is a routine task for me. I have fair knowledge of shell scripting. So if anyone can guide me even with rough outline of a script for this then i can do tweaks at my end. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> <sup>Update: the desired platform for the script has been clarified and a [vb-script](/questions/tagged/vb-script) response is no longer applicable. However, I will leave this response here in case a future viewer of this question stumbles upon it and finds it useful. Anyone writing a shell script in a Ubuntu language may be able to port over some aspects of this vbscript as well.</sup>

Here is something to get you started. If you record actions with Excel's macro recorder remember that using the same commands in a VBS means you have to get rid of all of the named parameters.

**prep_xlsx.vbs**

```
Set objExcel = WScript.CreateObject ("Excel.Application")

objExcel.Visible = true 'False  'True for testing

strFileName = "c:\tmp\vbs_test.xlsx"

 set objWb = objExcel.WorkBooks.open(strFileName)
 set objWs = objWb.Worksheets(1)

with objWs
    with .cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        .Cells.SpecialCells(4) = "**NewDATA**"  ' 4 is xlCellTypeBlanks
        .Cells.RemoveDuplicates 2, 1                ' Columns:=2, Header:=xlYes
        for c = 1 to .Columns.Count
            with .columns(c)
                .TextToColumns .Cells(1), 2 ', Array(0, 1)  'Range("C1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, 1)
            end with
        next    'next c
    end with
end with

objWb.Close True   'save on close

objExcel.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

It should be noted that removing leading / trailing spaces with the [Range.TextToColumns method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193593.aspx) with xlFixedWidth can attempt to split the column into two if there are too many leading spaces. Currently, this will halt the process as it will ask for confirmation on overwriting the next columns values (which you do not want to do). There has to be a significant number of spaces to have Excel guess that it belongs in two columns so unless there are more spaces than a typical word there is nothing to worry about; just something to be aware about. e.g. if there were twice as many leading spaces in D6, it might want to split across two columns.

[image: vbscript_before]
        <sup>vbs_test.xlsx before prep_xlsx.vbs</sup>

[image: vbscript_after]
        <sup>vbs_test.xlsx **after** prep_xlsx.vbs</sup>

Comment: Thanks, but you have provided solution in a VB script. I work completely on linux(debian) platform so i will not be able to use it. I need to write a shell script and schedule a cron job for this. Also i have very little knowledge to no knowledge about vb/.net. Do you know any parallel commands or functions in unix shell in shell that can give me the same output.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is choose a single scripting platform that you are comfortable with and add that to the tech tags that go along with your question. I mistakenly added [vb-script]; you should remove it. Add one language tag that you would like to see an answer in. Better yet, while you are editing the tag(s) in your question, provide what you have come up with so far and note your scripting language of choice in the narrative. If any of that had been done to start with, I wouldn't have wasted my time and yours providing an answer that you have no use for.

Comment: Sorry Jeeped, I didn't edit the tags correctly but i had mentioned shell script in subject and body, but i guess it is still useful info for someone looking for topic

Comment: No worries; just interested in getting you a focused answer to your question. I mistook the **'shell script'** for [vb-script] because vbscript does not run in Excel's VBA. It runs within its own command interpreter (WSCRIPT) or a command shell (CSCRIPT).